# Php write files and save as .java

Tags: java, php, file

In php I wan to write code into a file and compile it in a server.

But the fopen()  always create a file with .txt, is there a way I can create a file using php and write it into a file and save it with .java extension?

Comment: What code are you using, you can change the file extension pretty easily (if you have access to the actual script).

Comment: Not a PHP whiz, but can't you just specify the extension: `$file = fopen("test.java", "w");`

Comment: I am using PHP. I wan the text to be written into a file so that it can be compile straight away in the server. So its a problem now, since php always write into a file with txt extension.

Comment: Ummmmm... the better question, perhaps, is _why_ you want to do this. Generally speaking, dynamically generated server-side code isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

fopen creates a file with whatever name you give. For example:

```
$fp = fopen("TestClass.java", "a+");
```

*Notice the **a+** flag, which will open / create the file and puts the file pointer at the end of it*